# op_Division and Data Types in powershell

Tags: powershell, types, division, type-conversion

Hi I am having a problem with some powershell I am using to detect screen resolution and then divide width by height.

```
$width = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_VideoController).CurrentHorizontalResolution
$height = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_VideoController).CurrentVerticalResolution
$result = $width / $height
echo $width
echo $height
echo $result
```

Basically the problem is with the third line above. I get an error along the lines of this in the PS console.

```
Method invocation failed because [System.Object[]] does not contain a method named 'op_Division'.
```

I kind of understand what's going on here. The variables $width and $height aren't in the correct type e.g. decimal or double. The problem is I have no idea how to assign this type to these variables. I have tried the following.

```
[double]$width = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_VideoController).CurrentHorizontalResolution
[double]$height = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_VideoController).CurrentVerticalResolution
[double]$result = $width / $height
echo $width
echo $height
echo $result
```

The problem is that I get this error in the PS console.

```
Cannot convert the "System.Object[]" value of type "System.Object[]" to type "System.Double".
```

So basically it can't convert the $width and $height variables to the type I need to be able to divide the resulting numbers which it seems are of type System.Object[].

Can anyone please point me in the right direction? I am fairly new to powershell so am learning as I go I think anything I learn from this will be incredibly useful in my journey to becoming a fluent powersheller. Any help is also greatly appreciated.

PS - this seemed to work on Windows 7 running powershell 4.0 but I am using my home PC now which is Windows 8.1 running powershell 4.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
$width = ((Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_VideoController).CurrentHorizontalResolution)[0]
$height = ((Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_VideoController).CurrentVerticalResolution)[0]
$result = $width / $height
echo $width
echo $height
echo $result
```

IMHO `(Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_VideoController).CurrentHorizontalResolution` return an array for solutions with two or more monitors.
In case of more than one monitor you need to cycle the array.

Comment: Brilliant, tanks for your help!

Comment: There's a problem with this: I have two monitors but the Get-WmiObject call returns nothing for the first monitor for the horizontal and vertical resolution. So your code actually just gives an "Attempted to divide by zero" error on my machine.

Comment: @ducan are you running the console in the actual 'first' monitor or in the 'second'?

Comment: @CB Good question, I was running the console on the builtin laptop monitor which is configured as the secondary monitor but is the one that gives the first result in the output. My primary monitor is the external one which is returning its resolution. Running the console on the other monitor makes no difference to the output.

Comment: @duncan maybe `CurrentHorizontalResolution` returns alway an array type with no 'simple human like me' reason ;)

Comment: It's the Get-WmiObject that returns an array with one entry for each video controller. The CurrentHorizontalResolution field is a single value but Powershell field access on an array gives you the field value for each element of the array.

Comment: Totally understand this now and have learned a lot to boot thanks both CB and Duncan. It would seem CB answered the op_Division question and Duncan has improved on the approach to achieving the end result. Thanks again both.

Answer (score 3):

There is a problem with this. In some cases `Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_VideoController` returns an object with the resolution values unset.

e.g. on my system:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_VideoController | select-object Caption,CurrentHorizontalResolution,CurrentVerticalResolution

Caption                                                  CurrentHorizontalResolution                              CurrentVerticalResolution                              
-------                                                  ---------------------------                              -------------------------                              
NVIDIA GeForce GT 730M                                                                                                                                                   
Intel(R) HD Graphics Family                              1280                                                     1024
```

A more reliable way to get the result you want:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

PS C:\Windows\system32> [System.Windows.Forms.Screen]::AllScreens | 
select @{n='Width';e={$_.WorkingArea.Width}}, @{n='Height';e={$_.WorkingArea.Height}},
    @{n='Ratio';e={$_.WorkingArea.Width / $_.WorkingArea.Height }} | ft -AutoSize

Width Height            Ratio
----- ------            -----
 1218   1024      1.189453125
 1600    900 1.77777777777778
```

or:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> [System.Windows.Forms.Screen]::AllScreens | 
select @{n='Width';e={$_.Bounds.Width}}, @{n='Height';e={$_.Bounds.Height}},
    @{n='Ratio';e={$_.Bounds.Width / $_.Bounds.Height }} | ft -AutoSize

Width Height            Ratio
----- ------            -----
 1280   1024             1.25
 1600    900 1.77777777777778
```

depending whether you wanted the working area of the screen (which may exclude the start bar) or the full size of the monitor (which includes it).

**Edit:** In fact, what you probably want is:

```
PS C:\> $size = ([System.Windows.Forms.Screen]::AllScreens |? Primary).Bounds.Size

PS C:\> $result = $size.Width/$size.Height

PS C:\> $result
1.25
```

which just gives you the ratio for the primary display.

Comment: this method does indeed seem far superior than querying the Win32_VideoController class in WMI. I am going to change my script to use this method. Thank you!